# Locate text in the middle of TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView:

```
            <TextView
                android:text="Temperature"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"></TextView>
```

How to move text in the middle of component?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this parameter in your TextView tag.

```
android:gravity="center"
```